# Need an input dialog to populate with text

Tags: java, swing

I am a student at ISU. I was working on a homework assignment where I wanted to get text that was selected (highlighted) in a TextArea to appear in a JOptionPane dialog. I tried many of the methods for JOptionPane, but I could not get any of them to place the text the user selected in the input field of the dialog.

I guess that I could make a one element String array and pass this to the JOptionPane constructor listed.

JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType, Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)

This is not way I wanted to implement the JOptionPane. Please give me any help you can. Thanks and there is no hurry as the assignment has been handed in.

Comment: Post your code. What you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows how to use JOptionPane and how to get input from the user.

Read it to see if works for you or not.

[How to make dialogs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

> *I guess that I could make a one element String array and pass this to the JOptionPane constructor listed.*

Sounds correct to me.

> *This is not way I wanted to implement the JOptionPane.*

What's wrong with that? Or how do you want to implement it?

Take a look at that article perhaps you could manage to write something like:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, getSelectedTextFrom( someTextArea ) , "Message");
```

Where the method:

```
String getSelectedTextFrom( JTextArea )
```

Will return... well the selected text from the text area... :)

Comment: While your answer did not give me the code I needed directly, I was able to guess what I had to do using the JOptionPane constructor I gave. I now have my input dialog box populated with the text that had been selected in a TextArea. Thanks. Here is the line of code if you would like to see it.

    findTxt = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(findDialog, "Text to find?", "Question", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, textArea.getSelectedText());

Comment: I'm glad. It was a bit hard to know what code to post since I have no clue what did you have already.